# Objective C can't read text file when running on iPhone

Tags: objective-c

I've made an app that is relying on reading and writing a plist-file. This works well when I'm running the app in the iPhone simulator, but doesn't work at all when I'm testing it on my iPhone. I've also made a pre made text file in .txt format with demo data. The app works when I'm running this file.

All the reading and writing is done in a class that looks like this:

```
    -(void)saveArray:(NSMutableArray *)inputArray
{
    albumArray = inputArray;
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentFolder = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentFolder stringByAppendingFormat:@"albums.plist"];
    [albumArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

**Update**: Changed the string from "stringByAppendingFormat" to "stringByAppendingPathComponent" and it seems to work now. Thanks a lot! You guys made my day made.

Comment: stringByAppendingFormat should be stringByAppendingPathComponent ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure, that the folders already exist?
Here is a function i'm using to get the path to my file:

```
- (NSString*) pathToSavedAlbums
{
    NSURL *applicationSupportURL = [self applicationDataDirectory];

    if (! [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[applicationSupportURL path]])
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[applicationSupportURL path]
                                  withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                                   attributes:nil
                                                        error:&error];
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"error creating app support dir: %@", error);
        }
    }
    NSString *path = [[applicationSupportURL path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"albums.plist"];

    return path;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling of the plist name as well as the case, device is case sensitive for docs but simulator isn't. Also try deleting the app from the device and reinstalling it ?

`writeToFile:atomically:` returns a bool, so check that to see if it fails to even write to the path. Check the file path string and ensure this is where you want it to go.

Comment: Thanks! The function is returning 0 which should mean that it failed writing the file. Now I'll have to find out why it isn't working on my phone.

Comment: That'll be the problem. Check @lootsch answer, this may help.